# How can assign a value to column name and create a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, variables

Variable column has different values such as: "Municipal waste generated" and "Recycling" then the Value columns provide values for "Municipal waste generated" and "Recycling". How can I have two different variables such as Municipal waste generated and Recycling?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?  If you want to have multiple variable columns based on whether it is "Municipal waste generated" or 'Recycling',  you may try **pd.get_dummies(df.Variable)**

Comment: In the column called "Variable" there are two values I am interested: "Recycling" and "Municipal waste generated". Varibale column has more than two variables but I am only interested in Recyling and Municipal waste generated. I would like to have two columns that are "Recycling" and "Municipal waste generated" but in the dataframe those are just values.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the rows where `Variable` column is either "Recycling" or "Municipal waste generated", you can use `query` :

```py
df = # your dataframe
result = df.query('Variable.isin(("Recycling", "Municipal waste generated"))').copy()

result
```

Comment: The error: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. Does it take "," as a argument? It gave me an error.

Comment: My bad, it takes one argument : an iterator (list or tuple for example). I fixed my code.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code - **PIVOT** is used https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4,5,6],'Variable':["Municipal waste generated",'Weird Value',"Recycling","Municipal waste generated","Recycling","Recycling"]})

pd.pivot(df[(df['Variable']=="Municipal waste generated")|(df['Variable']=="Recycling")],
         index='ID',
         columns = 'Variable',
         values='Variable',
         ).reset_index()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! I need the values for those variables (Municipal waste generated and Recycling) to come from the variable named "Value". Would it take right values if I make values='Value'. Final point, is that I do not have index (besides the default one) I hope the code would work without index argument ?

Comment: yeah you can use values='REQUIRED COLUMN'. To you index question, above code use dummy column 'ID', it can be any column that you want against which you need these values. For details refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: I almost have the desired outcome but one thing remained. I want only one row for each country and year. For example, in your example where Municipal waste generated is a value Recycling is NaN. I want to have in this country in this year this is the Municipal waste generated and this is the Recycling. How can I have it? Thank you!

Comment: So you are saying you dont want rows where there is NaN values in any of the column "Municipal waste generated" or "Recycling"?

Comment: Yes, I need two values. So I can compute the percentage of recycling and I can have one value as a percentage for year and country.  Like 2007 AUS 30%